# Convert NSArray to specific object type without loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I'm trying to cast an object in an `NSArray`; the below loop clearly explains what I'm trying to achieve, but can I do it without a loop?

```
NSArray* inputs = [star activeStars];
for (Galaxy* object in inputs) {
    HBLogDebug(@"%@",object.name);
}
```

So I could perform searching in one line like below:

```
int foundInt = [inputs indexOfObject:@"somestar"];
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the element whose name property is equal to "somestar" without looping over the array and breaking when you find it?

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Comment: I am not sure this is feasible, I'll think about it twice. It would have been better if you had a NSDictionary<String *, Galaxy *> instead of NSArray where the key would be the name of the star, and the value would be the Galaxy object. It is like creating an index in a database to facilite the lookup of data based on that index.

Comment: See the "Finding Objects in an Array" section of the `NSArray` documentation.

Comment: You are looking for that https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1408043-indexofobjectpassingtest?language=objc Using it like this: `NSUInteger index = [matches indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(Galaxy * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) { return [obj name] == @"somestar";}];`

Comment: Fo one liners you need "kvc collection operators" https://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/  [[star activeStars] valueForKeyPath:@"name"]; however if you need to filter the correct answer is above